# removing leap year data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'mydf' with following format

```
---------------------------
index month day year
---------------------------
```

'mydf' size original size is 1600

and want to eliminate leap year data

so I have written following command

```
leapdf =  mydf.loc[(mydf['month'] == 2) & (mydf['day'] == 29) ]
```

here size of leapdf returned as 83

If i try other way as below

```
otherdf =  mydf.loc[(mydf['month'] != 2) & (mydf['day'] != 29) ]
```

Here i am expecting size of otherdf is 1517. But size returned is different which is much less? I am not sure what mistake I am making. Please correct me

Answer (score 1):

I think second solution is OK, but `loc` can be omit if need all columns:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'month':[2,3,7],'day':[29,24,20]})

#invert boolean mask by ~
leapdf =  mydf[~((mydf['month'] == 2) & (mydf['day'] == 29)) ]
print (leapdf)
   day  month
1   24      3
2   20      7

#get all rows if NOT month 2 or NOT day 29
leapdf =  mydf[((mydf['month'] != 2) | (mydf['day'] != 29)) ]
print (leapdf)
   day  month
1   24      3
2   20      7
```

If need only one column:

```
leapdf =  mydf.loc[((mydf['month'] != 2) | (mydf['day'] != 29)), 'day']
print (leapdf)
1    24
2    20
Name: day, dtype: int64
```

Alternative solution:

```
leapdf =  mydf.query("month!= 2 | day != 29")
print (leapdf)
   day  month
1   24      3
2   20      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed in the second example.  `Month != 2 AND day !=29`  would exclude Jan 29, March 29, June 29  etc..

You want `(month != 2) || (month =2 & day != 29)`